# Зачем для input type=file создают еще одноименное поле type=hidden, например, в yii2?

Tags: php, javascript, html, yii2, веб-программирование

```
<div class="form-group field-fruit-screens">
    <input type="hidden" name="Fruit[screens]" value="">
    <input type="file" id="fruit-screens" name="Fruit[screens]">
    <div class="help-block"></div>
</div>
```

Вот такой получается элемент формы в yii2.

Comment: если вы спрашиваете за конкретный случай уии-два, не ставьте лишние теги к вопросу. тем более, что вопрос звучит более чем обобщённо. с уважением.

Comment: @KirillKorushkin вопрос и есть обобщенный. Yii2 - это один фреймворк, в котором применено такое решение, но наверняка оно может потребоваться не только в нем.

Answer (score 0):

В фреймворках я такое встречал, когда требовалось инициализировать значением поле формы. Например, если выводится чекбокс, то, если его не нажать, его значение не пойдет на сервер. Тогда на сервере надо проверять, если чекбокс не пришел, значит его не нажали. Некоторые фреймворки вместо этого делают так:

```
<input type="hidden" name="option" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="option" value="1" />
```

В таком случае, если чекбокс не нажали, то пойдет значение "0", иначе пойдет "0", а за ним "1". Последнее значение перезаписывает предыдущие, т.е. при разборе будет "1".

Скорее всего в Yii2 для файла сделано с той же целью.

Comment: Стоит заметить, что само по себе последнее значение не перезаписывает предыдущие, и на сервер будут отправлены одновременно 0 и 1, а дальше фреймворк будет разбираться какое именно значение брать

Comment: Правда, ещё стоит заметить, что `input type="file"` это не касается, так как в случае отсутствия файла там и так отправится пустое значение (по крайней мере в Firefox и Chrome), так что на вопрос это не совсем отвечает

Comment: Фрейворк не будет разбираться, какое значение брать. Последнее значение перезапишет предыдущее на сервере, при преобразовании query в массив. А при отправке через AJAX вообще пойдут сразу смерженые данные.

Comment: Про input[type=file] для интереса прочитал пост от разработчика. Там он писал, что это костыль, связаный с валидацией модели.

Comment: Массивы бывают разные, можно прочитать query так, чтобы сохранить все значения)

Comment: Мы вроде бы говорили про PHP + Yii, а не абстрактно про протоколы и алгоритмы.

Comment: У Yii2 приписано «например» и в комменте написано «вопрос и есть обобщенный», так что мы говорим именно что абстрактно про протоколы и алгоритмы)

Answer (score 0):

Это сделано для случая, когда ваша форма содержит только поле ввода файла. Если вы нажмете submit, но файл не будет выбран, то тогда на сервер отправится пустой пост и в $_POST[$formName] ничего не будет.
Этот кейс может проявляться при редактировании модели через такую форму.

А так как там будет как минимум hidden-поле вы сможете определить что именно эту форму засабмитили.